# Share YouTube video on Facebook via API

Tags: facebook, api, youtube, share

This is probably not possible, but I'm throwing it out here for anyone with crazy awesome ideas or if they happened to come across some morsel of information about it.

I have an embedded YouTube player (iFrame) using the API, with a custom JS control bar. All that works great.

I want to have a share option, however, since the videos on my site will often appear as overlays, it's not ideal to have the page be shared, but rather the video itself. Is there a way to have a user share the YouTube link directly from my page, rather than just a link to my site?

I already realize the fallback is to create a URL on my site that takes a video id parameter and redirects to the proper youtube page.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the embed video from YouTube include all YouTube features by default?

(Thumbs up, share, full screen, etc…)

Comment: Read: custom control bar. The parameters or a call to use the innate YouTube implementation of Sharing does not seem to exist.

Comment: No, you cannot implement a custom flash control bar for videos on Facebook. They'll only add the "play" functionality if it is from a major video site.